# How to PUT Object AWS-S3 CORS and not get CORS Error?

Tags: javascript, http, amazon-s3

I am trying to PUT an Object to S3 from Javascript, via XMLHttpRequest().

The S3 Bucket is set with permissive CORS Configuration, but whatever I try I get error:-

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket>/direct/movie-1585318655303.mov' from origin 'https://<my-site>' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

My JavaScript PUT request is formed as follows:-

```
var reqURL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket>/direct/movie-'+Date.now()+'.mov';

var x = new XMLHttpRequest();

//x.withCredentials = false; ** MAKES NO DIFFERENCE **
//x.withCredentials = true;

x.onload = () => {
    console.log('x.responseText',x.responseText);    // Never Get this far !!
}

x.open('PUT',reqURL,true);

var blob = new Blob([resp.result]); // resp.result is from fileReader();

x.send(blob);
```

My AWS CORS Configuration is:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

The documentation I have found suggest setting `x.withCredentials` only when there is a specific Origin Domain restriction, which there isn't in this case since it's `'*'`. However AWS Support did say that I needed to send Origin Header must be passed, but I cannot find any advice online as to how I might do this.